# Paypal Express Checkout Security Header is not valid

Tags: java

I am integrating `Paypal Express Checkout` for a website, followed the steps on this [guide](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/expresscheckout?env=www).
Everything was fine in development using `Sandbox`.
But when I moved to `Paypal` live credentials

1. API Username
2. API Password
3. API Signature

I got the error:

> Security Header is not Valid using https://devtools- 
> paypal.com/guide/expresscheckout?env=www

Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually pertains to a typo in your creds or your sending it to the wrong endpoint for live.

Comment: I cross checked multiple times creds and endpoint are correct.

Comment: I got solution. need to enable express checkout from **Paypal**  account.

Comment: Interesting as you should have gotten a message stating express checkout not enable for this account but that's only for payflow with express; express checkout is turned on automatically. There isn't an on off toggle unless it's different for every country which I find very odd, but glad you got it!

Comment: Anil can you share your exact steps on how you got this to work please. Thanks.

Comment: GeekNinja  After login - profile and  settings - My selling tools - Website preferences - Express Checkout Settings  - Support giropay and bank transfer payments:  Yes